# Cut an uploaded YouTube video

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video to YouTube and now I want to cut it shorter using the YouTube Editor without having to save repost it as a new video.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's simple enough.

Go here `https://www.youtube.com/enhance?v=[Your video ID]`

Go to "trim".

Use the slider to change it as required.

Save changes (not save as new video).

Wait approx 30 minutes and it should have updated.